# how can I append the new data into existing file

Tags: python, kivy

i want to store the data given by the user in the local memory in a txt or json file, but the problem is that every time i save it in test.txt the new data is overwriting the previous one. I want to append the new data to the existing one. how can i do it? any help.

```
    # takes input from textfield and prints it on consol
    import kivy
    kivy.require("1.10.0")

    from kivy.app import App 
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    import json 

    class text(BoxLayout):
        textid = ObjectProperty()
        def printout(self):
            ddata=[]

            with open('test.txt','w') as outfile:
                entry={'word':self.textid.text}
                ddata.append(entry)
                json.dump(ddata,outfile)

    class TextFieldApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return text()

    t = TextFieldApp()
    t.run()
```

here is the kivy code:

```
    text:

    <text>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        textid: text_box
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: text_box
                size_hint_x: 75
            Button:
                text: "print"
                size_hint_x: 25
                on_press: root.printout()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open with 'a+' in order to append rather than write as:

```
# takes input from textfield and prints it on consol
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import json 

class text(BoxLayout):
    textid = ObjectProperty()
    def printout(self):
        ddata=[]

        with open('test.txt','a+') as outfile:#open to append to an existing file or a new file
            entry={'word':self.textid.text}
            ddata.append(entry)
            json.dump(ddata,outfile)

class TextFieldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return text()

t = TextFieldApp()
t.run()
```

For your printout function you could append to the word as so if you dont want to append word again:

```
def printout(self):
    ddata = []
    file_name = 'test.txt'
    with open(file_name,'rw+') as outfile:
            message = outfile.read()
            if message:
                vals = message
                wr = open(file_name, 'w')
                vals = vals[:len(message)-3] + str(self.textid.text) + vals[len(message)-3:]
                wr.write(vals)
                wr.close()
            else:
                entry={'word':str(self.textid.text)}
                ddata.append(entry)
                json.dump(ddata,outfile)
```

Comment: I tried that but heres what I am getting -   [{"word": "hghvghfgvgff\nhghgjghjgjg"}][{"word": "ksdufhcaslfhshl"}][{"word": "siefhypsiefypiefhlkafs"}]   every time i run my prog. and save something a new list is being created in the file but i want the new data to be appended in the same list everytime

Comment: There is an issue in your printout function, you are creating a new tuple with 'word' in your entry variable and appending it. so every time you execute it,the function creates a new word and appends to your file. what you need to do is read the file append to the existing 'word'